# Banner not displaying on top of web page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to test a banner I have created but seem to be having issues.

I was hoping I can see my banner and text on top of the page, both the success one and the failed one and for it to display an X in the divs of the banner so the banner can be closed.

Instead what happens is that I don’t see either banner on top of the page and the X is on the top corner of the website. If I click the X, it hides my web page.

Not sure what I am doing incorrectly so would like some guidance. I want both banners for now to appear top of the web page, their associated close icons (x) to be within each banner and if selected, the banner closes.

Below is my code:

```
    #stripe-info-success {
        display: block;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        background-color: green;
        width: 50%;
      }
      #stripe-info-success.visible {
        display: block;
      }

      #stripe-info-failure {
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        background-color: red;
        width: 50%;
      }
      #stripe-info-failure {
        display: block;
      }

      #close {
        float:right;
        display:inline-block;
        padding:2px 5px;
        color: black;
        background:#ccc;
    }

    #close:hover {
        float:right;
        display:inline-block;
        padding:2px 5px;
        background:black;
        color:#ccc;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

Hi,

I am trying to test a banner I have created but seem to be having issues.

I was hoping I can see my banner and text on top of the page, both the success one and the failed one and for it to display an X in the divs of the banner so the banner can be closed.

Instead what happens is that I don’t see either banner on top of the page and the X is on the top corner of the website. If I click the X, it hides my web page.

Not sure what I am doing incorrectly so would like some guidance. I want both banners for now to appear top of the web page, their associated close icons (x) to be within each banner and if selected, the banner closes.

Below is my code:

```
<div id="stripe-info-success">Your payment was successful
    <span id='close' onclick='this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode.parentNode); return false;'>X</span>
  </div>
  <div id="stripe-info-failure">Your payment was cancelled</div>
  <span id='close' onclick='this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode.parentNode); return false;'>X</span>
</div>

....

<script>
(".buynow").on("click", validate);

window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById('close').onclick = function(){
        this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode
        .removeChild(this.parentNode.parentNode);
        return false;
    };
};

</script>
```

Comment: Duplicating `#id` is bad. `#id` should be **unique**

Comment: you confused classes with ids. Use classes instead of ids in your code and it should work. Also please don't use `<span onclick..` You should rather use a `<button>` element for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
 #stripe-info-success {
        display: block;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        background-color: green;
        width: 50%;
      }
      #stripe-info-success.visible {
        display: block;
      }

      #stripe-info-failure {
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        float:right;
        right: 0;
        background-color: red;
        width: 50%;
      }
      #stripe-info-failure {
        display: block;
      }

      .close {
        float:right;
        display:inline-block;
        padding:2px 5px;
        color: black;
        background:#ccc;
    }

    .close:hover {
        float:right;
        display:inline-block;
        padding:2px 5px;
        background:black;
        color:#ccc;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
</style>
<body>
<div id="stripe-info-success">Your payment was successful
    <span class='close'>X</span>
  </div>
  <div id="stripe-info-failure">Your payment was cancelled
  <span class='close'>X</span></div>
</div>
<script>
window.onload = function(){
var label = document.getElementsByClassName('close');
for (var i = 0; i<label.length; i++) {
  label[i].onclick = function () {
  var el = (this.parentNode);
  el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
  };
}
};

</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

css:

```
#stripe-info-success {
  display:none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: green;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

jscript:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.close').click(function() {
   this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode
        .removeChild(this.parentNode.parentNode);
        return false;
});
});
</script>
```

Change the span id to button class. hope it helps.